# Syntax error - Unexpected Where MYSQL

Tags: mysql, where-clause

Don't really know MYSQL well just trying to transfer this SQLSERVER code to work in MYSQL

```
Select [SALARY],[BONUS],[COMM],
SUM (SALARY + BONUS + COMM)AS 
'Total Compensation'
FROM [Enterprise].[dbo].[Employee]
Where ED_LVL >= '16'
group by [SALARY],[BONUS],[COMM]
```

I obviously switched the tables name to fit mysql

Comment: Also, MySQL doesn't have schema names (AFAIK) so the route to your db / table will be `dbName.tableName` (ie, no `dbo`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `[]`

```
SELECT SALARY,BONUS,COMM,
SUM (SALARY + BONUS + COMM) AS 'Total Compensation'
FROM databaseName.Employee
WHERE ED_LVL >= 16
GROUP BY SALARY,BONUS,COMM
```